# Adding borders to d3 curves

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to add borders to d3 curves using a class selector ('curves') I've added to those objects with the .attr() method.  Why doesn't this add a border to the curves I have?

In the original code, I have several selectors that are successfully targeting the objects I'm intending, but for some reason when it comes to this particular d3 object it doesn't work well with CSS selectors (?).  I'd appreciate specific advice on this problem, but also more general advice on how to edit the appearance of d3 objects like these curves.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poller+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<head>
    <title> *** </title>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src='C:\Users\***\Google Drive\Code\jquery-1.11.1.js'></script>

    <style >

        .a{
            color:yellow;
            background:red;
            font-family: 'Poller One',verdana, arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .curves{
            border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            border-width: 20px;
            background-color: blue;
        }


    </style>

</head>

<body class="a">

    <div>
        <p align="center">Lorem Ipsum</p>

    </div>

    <dl>
        <dt>Defintion list item</dt>
        <dd>This is the definition</dd>

    </dl>

    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ol>
</body>

    <script>
        var data = [30,50,80,120,150,60,15];
        var r = 300;

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(['green','red','blue','orange','yellow','purple','magenta']);


        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1500)
            .attr("height", 1500);

        var group = canvas.append("g")
            .attr('transform', 'translate(300,300)');

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(125)
            .outerRadius(r);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie() //go inspect the objects in the browser
            .value(function (d) { return d; });

        var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc") // select everything with the arc class
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr('class', 'arc');

        arcs.append("path")
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function (d) { return color(d.data); })
            .attr('class', 'curves');


        arcs.append("text") 
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('font-size', '2em')
            .text(function (d) { return d.data; });

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar with how to break the code up so the jsfiddle site displays the same thing my .html file shows in the browser.  http://jsfiddle.net/T2vAL/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS definition for `curve` is using properties that you would use for regular HTML elements like a `<div>`. SVG elements like `<path>` use properties like `fill` and `stroke` to accomplish what you are trying to do. Here is a good article describing how to apply fill and stoke properties:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes